# Why is my background image cut off at the bottom by my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page in which the background image covers it without repeating or expanding beyond the window.  It is now cut off at the bottom.

I have tried using viewport sizes, percentages, and cover, but it either repeats or gets cut off and leaves almost half of the window totally white.

```css
html, body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:99vmin; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size:76%;
}
#background {
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OON2Kz3.jpg); 
    background-size: cover;
}
#quotes {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 30%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    color: beige;
    font-size: 36px;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="quotes">
        <p>&#8220;<a href="https://theunboundedspirit.com/ananda-coomaraswamy-quotes/">Art</a> is the supreme task and the truly metaphysical activity in this life.&#8221;</p>
        <p>&#8220;Underneath this reality in which we live and have our being, another and altogether different reality lies concealed.&#8221;</p>
        <p>&#8220;We obtain the concept, as we do the form, by overlooking what is individual and actual; whereas nature is acquainted with no forms and no concepts, and likewise with no species, but only with an X which remains inaccessible and undefinable for us.&#8221;</p>
    </div>
        </div>
    <button class="button">Thus Spoke Nietzsche</button>
<script src="randomize.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: How am I to know what code is relevant and what is not?  Code interacts with all kinds of other code.  Tell me a rule to follow.

Comment: @Thomas your issue is with `html` and `css` so we need to see both of those. Your issue pertains to your background, which means we need to see any element that you are adjusting the `background` property with. If you aren't sure what is relevant, I suggest going through your code line by line and ensure you know what it's doing. You may be able to find your issue.

Comment: @MikeDiglio I changed it.  I hope it is better.

Comment: @Paulie_D I changed it.  I hope it is better.

Comment: @Thomas In order to determine whether code is relevant, start with the code you have, then remove styles/markup until your snippet no longer reproduces the error you are describing. At least half the time, this should also help you discover what the problem is on your own (which is a major reason why we require an MCVE). Sometimes you can also use deduction; e.g. for the problem you've described, any code that might change the font color or style obviously is not relevant to a background-image sizing problem, and thus should not be included in the code snippet.

Comment: @Thomas Regarding your code, I've converted it to a runnable snippet, but it's still not quite a self-contained demo; can you please upload your background image so that you can use an absolute URL for us to see?

Comment: @TylerH Here is a link to the image: https://imgur.com/a/LAND4ie

Comment: @Thomas I've added it to your question for now, but in the future you should edit your question to include it, yourself

Comment: Also, if the purpose of the #background `div` is just to have a background covering the whole page, why not apply the background styles to the `body` element instead?

Comment: @TylerH I will bear in mind in the future more of the principles you outlined.  It was hard for me to learn any better when all I received was downvotes without explanation.  Because of people like you, I can learn to get better at asking the right questions and learn what is relevant, because I do not know everything that may be relevant, since code is often unpredictable especially at an earlier stage of learning to code.  I will practice narrowing down the code as you suggested.

Comment: @Thomas If you have any other issues with this, don't hesitate to comment; sometimes people get solutions weeks, months, or years later (though that's of course not ideal)!

Answer (score 1):

try this with `img`

```css
#background{
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:1; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<img id="background" src="https://i.imgur.com/OON2Kz3.jpg" alt="" title="">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want full image as background try - background-size: 100% 100%; or background-size: 100%;